# Simplified vector calculus expression?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra

Given a function $A : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and a function $y : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, is there an abbreviated/simplified form of

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial a_{ij}}{\partial x_j} \frac{\partial y}{\partial x_i}$$

? If it helps you can assume $A$ is symmetric. It seems like this is:

$$\sum_{j=1}^n \nabla y \cdot v_j$$

where $v_j$ is the vector with components $\frac{\partial a_{ij}}{\partial x_j}$ for $i=1,\dots,n$. But I can't think of a briefer way to describe $v_j$, nor a way to abbreviate the sum over $j$.

Comment: @gerw You're welcome to post that as an answer. (I assume that similarly $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\partial^2 a_{ij}}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$ can be understood as $\operatorname{div}(\operatorname{div}(A))$?)

Comment: Done. Yes, this sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would denote this as $\operatorname{div}(A) \cdot \nabla y$. Here, $\operatorname{div}$ is the row-wise (or column-wise) divergence.